# What is that thing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, monster-design

[image: pathfinder core book page 404]

Anyone know what this is and in which bestiary i can find it?

Answer (score 7):

Yes...

That is  [Treerazer](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Treerazer)
(it's a he, and a unique) and it is from *The Inner Sea World Guide*, pg(s). 314